# Lines missing in the graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The code

```
\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={mark=none}}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title=QWS Dataset,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        ytick={0,0.2,...,1},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        xtick={0,1,...,10},
        scaled ticks=false,
        log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis line style=-,
        minor tick style={draw=none},
        ylabel = Fitness,
       cycle list={
                black,thick,densely dotted\\
                blue,densely dashed\\
                red,solid\\
            },
        xlabel = Number of Generations,
         every axis legend/.append style={xshift=-10pt}
        ]
        %manman
        \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(1,0.1)(2,0.1)(3,0.1)(4,0.1)(5,0.1)(6,0.1)(7,0.1)(8,0.1)(9,0.1)(10,0.1)};
    \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(1,0.5)(2,0.5)(3,0.5)(4,0.5)(5,0.5)(6,0.5)(7,0.5)(8,0.5)(9,0.5)(10,0.5)};
    \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(1,0.8)(2,0.8)(3,0.8)(4,0.8)(5,0.8)(6,0.8)(7,0.8)(8,0.8)(9,0.8)(10,0.8)};
\legend{FV,FC,TAS}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Experiment Results}\vspace{-5mm}
\end{figure}
```

the graph
[image]

I wish to have three lines, but why only two lines are there?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you specify 10 coordinates for the `x` axis in each horizontal line? You could change those for something like `coordinates{(1,0.1)(10,0.1)}` and get the same result.

Comment: @william007 Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your third line is there, but it and the x-axis are superimposed, because your y ticks start at 0.1. Setting `ymin=0` in the options of your `axis` environment solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={mark=none}}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title=QWS Dataset,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        ytick={0,0.2,...,1},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        xtick={0,1,...,10},
        scaled ticks=false,
        log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis line style=-,
        minor tick style={draw=none},
        ylabel = Fitness,
       cycle list={
                black,thick,densely dotted\\
                blue,densely dashed\\
                red,solid\\
            },
        xlabel = Number of Generations,
         every axis legend/.append style={xshift=-10pt}
        ]
        %manman
        \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(1,0.1)(2,0.1)(3,0.1)(4,0.1)(5,0.1)(6,0.1)(7,0.1)(8,0.1)(9,0.1)(10,0.1)};
    \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(1,0.5)(2,0.5)(3,0.5)(4,0.5)(5,0.5)(6,0.5)(7,0.5)(8,0.5)(9,0.5)(10,0.5)};
    \addplot+[mystyle] plot  coordinates{(1,0.8)(2,0.8)(3,0.8)(4,0.8)(5,0.8)(6,0.8)(7,0.8)(8,0.8)(9,0.8)(10,0.8)};
\legend{FV,FC,TAS}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Experiment Results}\vspace{-5mm}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]